# Why is it a variable that was created with dplyr is not showing in the new dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am analyzing a Demographic and Health Survey data set. I am in the phase of creating variables. I created a variable using dplyr and mutate, but when I use the function exist to find out whether it is in the new data frame, it does not exist. Why is this so?

I tried to create a new variable using hw70_1 and hw73_1 with a new modified data frame, but I am getting an error that says hw73_1 does not exist. Why is this happening?

```
>dm <- datamatrix %>% mutate(hw73_1=case_when(hw73< -200~1, hw73>= -200~0))

> exists("hw73_1", list2env(dm))

[1] TRUE

> dm <- datamatrix %>% mutate(hw74_1=case_when(hw70_1==0 & hw73_1==0 ~ 0, hw70_1==1 & hw73_1==1~ 1, TRUE ~ 99))

Error: Problem with mutate()
input hw74_1.
x object 'hw73_1' not found
i Input hw74_1 is case_when(...).´ –
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line of code uses `datamatrix` as the input, but it's `dm` that has the `hw73_1` variable defined.

(This is really a programming question rather than a statistics question; the stackoverflow.com programming site would have been a better place to ask)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Thomas's answer, this is what you need for the second line of code:

`dm <- dm %>% mutate(hw74_1=case_when(hw70_1==0 & hw73_1==0 ~ 0, hw70_1==1 & hw73_1==1~ 1, TRUE ~ 99))`